# Redirection is not working when there is 404 error in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to redirect the user to an action method page when there is a 404 error. For example, my domain is `www.test.com`, but when the user navigates to `www.test.com/abc/def`, then I want to redirect the user to a specific 404 page.

Here is my code in `program.cs`:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    EnteredPath = context.Request.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString().Remove(0, 1);
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        context.Request.Path="/URL/checkRawUrl";
        await next();
    }
});
```

It's not working - my controller name is `URL` and action name is `checkRawUrl`.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

**Note** It must be added before routing configs like app.UseRouting();.... Please check it.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    string EnteredPath = context.Request.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString().Remove(0, 1);
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/URL/checkRawUrl";
        await next();
    }
});
app.UseRouting();
```